# Teiid Springboot starter file datasource

Tags: xml, spring-boot, file, teiid

Using Teiid Springboot I would like to consume xml files from disk. I used to work with the old EAP/Wildfly Teiid project and the way to solve this was to use a resource adapter and then call a procedure to read the data.

With Springboot what steps do I need to take to create a datasource/resource adapter that can be used in my DDL VDB.
I already had a look at the FTP example below, so my assumption would be to create a FileConnectionFactory:
https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/tree/master/samples/ftp
However, there is no use of a DDL file and my preference is to parse the XML in the DDL (unless there is a better way to expose the this data in my DDL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using DDL based VDB, you can define the file-based connection by supplying the following properties in the `application.properties`

```
spring.teiid.file.foo.parent-directory=path/to/myfile
```

where `foo` is your file resource name, which needs to be used in VDB, for example: (`accounts` is the name given for schema)

```
CREATE SERVER foo FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file;
CREATE SCHEMA accounts SERVER foo;
```

then in a view transformation, you can use the above schema and read the file as

```
create view something(...) AS
  select x.* from 
    (exec accounts.getTextFiles()) f, 
    xmltable('/a' PASSING xmlparse(document f.file) COLUMNS first string, second integer) x
```

For more details about using `xmltable` see http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_xmltable.html